# Oh no! Something has gone wrong. A problem has ocurred and the system can't recover. Please contact a system administrator

Tags: fedora

I attempted  `yum update` while installing VLC player so while updating my system got shutdown without my presence.
After that when i wanted to reboot my system im getting an error
`"Oh no! Something has gone wrong. A problem has ocurred and the system can't recover. Please contact a system administrator"`
Did anybody ever face that problem, do you know what solution could work ?

Comment: That's a wonderfully uninformative message. What version of Fedora is this?

Comment: Wow, that's as useful as a Windows error! Can you tell us at which point you're getting the error? Can you boot into rescue mode?

Comment: Faheem Mitha- I'm using Fedora 16

Comment: kernel panic and not able to boot into rescue mode also-terdon

Comment: While booting, does `grub` show you a menu?  If so, edit the `linux` line and remove `rhgb` and `quiet`, then allow it to try to boot.  Ton's of messages should stream down your screen and hopefully some of them will help diagnosis the problem(s).

Comment: I'm getting this error: BUG-unable to handle kernel paging request at ffffffffffffff8 and gnome shell seems to be deleted.

Answer (score -1):

I would boot into single user mode and remove that package from your repo

```
yum remove <package-name>
yum clean
reboot
```

Comment: I tried it but i'm getting an error: no such package found and no package to removal

Comment: Actually i wanted to install VLC Player so by seeing this site http://www.gofedora.in/2012/06/install-vlc-media-player-201-on-fedora.html i followed those steps after step 1 and 2 when i gave yum update it was updating something but after few minuets it automatically got shutdown and not getting booted to fedora .   Do you know what solution could work ?